# Problems to transform data and generate histogram

Tags: r

I'm starting to learn R so I am trying to do basic statistical analyses like transform data and generate histogram however, I got some problems and have no idea how to solve it.

My data has some negative values so I add a constante `df_4$constant1 <- add(20, df_4)` and apply the formula `log.tras <- log(df_4$constant1)`.  Until here everything works well, when use `summary()`.

When I run the formulas below  I got a error name,

> Error in hist.default(log.tras): 'x' must be numeric

```
frequency_log <- (log.tras)
hist(log.tras)
plot(frequency_log)
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without some data - we have to guess what the problem is - can you post the data in dput format?

Comment: I presume the OP is referring to `magrittr::add`, an alias for `+`. But in any case I think it was meant to read `df_4$constant1 <- add(df_4$constant1, 20)`, equivalent to `df4$constant1 <- df4$constant1 + 20`.

Comment: Reel one to SO! Please, provide a [mcve] which helps others to reproduce the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know the function add in R ? if by adding a constant you mean x + 20 why not using "+" ?

your error just tell that your log.tras is not numeric. Try `str(log.tras)` or `class(log.tras)` and you will have some information about the type of your objet.

then if you use the function hist(object) there is no need to use plot, it will plot the histogram, the args plot is by default equal to TRUE

Comment: data.frame': 1000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ data_4: num  2.87 2.97 3.14 3.14 3.24 ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope your add() function does something similar to below:

```
function add(20, df_4){
   return df_4$constant1 + 20
}
```

If yes, can you please do a **str()** on the log.tras and check for the data types of this data frame. The type of this variable needs to be a 'numeric' in order to invoke the hist() function. So can you please verify the type of this variable again as below?

```
str(log.tras)
```

If the variable type is numeric, you should be able to safely call the hist() function.

Comment: data.frame': 1000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ data_4: num  2.87 2.97 3.14 3.14 3.24 ...

Comment: Even been numeric, the function hist() does not work =\